# Registering a receiver on a button click

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I am creating an app in which a **receiver** of type **BroadcastReciever** will be registered PROGRAMMATICALLY  on a button click. i.e., when the user presses the button on the app, the receiver has to get registered. And again when another button is clicked, the *OnDestroy() method* is called and the receiver is unregistered.

The coding goes like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private BroadcastReceiver receiver=new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {//Perform tasks here}
    };
    private  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.CALL");
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {           
            registerReceiver(receiver,filter);
            }
    });

    final Button buttonEnd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);
    buttonEnd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onDestroy();
            finish();
        }
    });
        }

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
```

But the receiver does not get registered which throws an exception while unregistering it.

Note:
I've even tried the IntentFilter action as **android.intent.action.MAIN** but no use.

Where am I wrong?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: This doesn't answer why the receiver doesn't get registered but don't call `onDestroy()` directly. By calling `finish()` your `Activity` will be exited gracefully and `onDestroy()` will be called by the system anyway. Also, post the logcat which shows the exception.

Comment: Which exception is thrown?

Comment: Thinking about it `android.intent.action.CALL` and `android.intent.action.MAIN` aren't things you can listen for with a receiver. They are `Intent` actions used to start another `Activity` that you wan't to perform the action.

Comment: Thanks Squonk. What else do I have to do??

Comment: invalidArgumentException is thrown.